# How to keep the current output of data after refreshing from querying data from firestore to my chat application?

Tags: javascript, firebase, web-applications, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

```js
  db.collection("Users").doc(email).collection("Messages").doc(email).collection("user").onSnapshot(function(querySnapshot) { querySnapshot.docChanges.forEach(function(change)
        {
              
               if (change.type === "added") {
               
                   chat_div.innerHTML +="<div class='container'><h3 id='eventN'> "+change.doc.data().date +" :" + change.doc.data().message +  " </h3></div>";
                   
                   
                   
                
                }
             
              
          });
    
    
    });
    db.collection("Users").doc(email).collection("Messages").doc(email).collection("admin").onSnapshot(function(querySnapshot) { querySnapshot.docChanges.forEach(function(change)
        {
              
               if (change.type === "added") {
               
                   chat_div.innerHTML +="<div class='container darker'><h3 id='eventN'> "+change.doc.data().date +" :" + change.doc.data().message +  " </h3></div>";
                
                }
             
              
          });
    
 
    });
      send_div.innerHTML +="<div class='send'><input id='message' type='text'><button type='submit' onClick='subMessage(\""+email+"\")'>submit</button></div>";
     
}
```

So I tried making a chat web application using Javascript and Html with a  Firestore database. Everything works when I query each message is alternating from admin to the user. But once I refresh the page that messages group up from admin to user. Everything is already real time the only problem is they group each other after refreshing the page.

[Here is when i don't refresh the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PG81p.png)

[Here is after i refresh the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mwouk.png)

```js
db.collection("Users").doc(email_id).collection("Messages").doc(email_id).collection("user").onSnapshot(function(querySnapshot) { querySnapshot.docChanges.forEach(function(change)
        {
              
               if (change.type === "added") {
               
                   chat_div.innerHTML +="<div class='container'><h3 id='eventN'> "+change.doc.data().date +" :" + change.doc.data().message +  " </h3></div>";
                }
          });
    
 
    });
```

```html
<h2>User</h2>
    
<div id="chat_div">

</div>
    
<div class="send_message">
    <input id="message"type="text">
    <button onClick="subMessage();" type="submit">Send</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please also specify what you have already tried ? If you haven't tried anything yet, please do start and then ask a question when you are stuck. Please provide some code. Please also take a moment to read [how-to-ask on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, your problem is that the order of the messages changes when you refresh the page.  Is this correct?  If so, this can be easily fixed.  If this is not the case, please can you edit your question, to make it easier to understand what you mean by "group each other"

### Sort in ascending order

```
db.collection("Users").doc(email_id).collection("Messages").doc(email_id).collection("user").orderBy("date").onSnapshot
```

### Sort in descending order

```
db.collection("Users").doc(email_id).collection("Messages").doc(email_id).collection("user").orderBy("date", "desc").onSnapshot
```